# how to get process status ( running , killed ) event?

Tags: c++, linux, events, process, status

How to I get the status of another process?

i want to know the execution status of another process.

i want to receive and process the event as a inotify.

no search /proc by periods.

how to another process status (running , killed ) event?

SYSTEM : linux, solaris, aix

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Linux**

Under Linux (and probably many Unixes system) you can achieve this by using the `ptrace` call, then using waitpid to wait for status:

manpages:

- ptrace call: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html
- waitpid call: https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid

From the manpage:

> Death under ptrace
>         When a (possibly multithreaded) process receives a killing signal
>         (one whose disposition is set to SIG_DFL and whose default action is
>         to kill the process), all threads exit.  Tracees report their death
>         to their tracer(s).  Notification of this event is delivered via
>         waitpid(2).

beware that you will need to have special authorization in certain cases. Take a look at `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`. (if you can modify the target program, you can also change the behavior of ptrace by calling `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, nullptr, nullptr);`

To use ptrace, first you must get your process PID, then call `PTRACE_ATTACH`:

```
// error checking removed for the sake of clarity
#include <sys/ptrace.h>

pid_t child_pid;

// ... Get your child_pid somehow ...

// 1. attach to your process:

long err; 
err = ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, child_pid, nullptr, nullptr);


// 2. wait for your process to stop:
int process_status;

err = waitpid(child_pid, &process_status, 0);

// 3. restart the process (continue)
ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, nullptr, nullptr);

// 4. wait for any change in status:

err = waitpid(child_pid, &process_status, 0);
// while waiting, the process is running... 
// by default waitpid will wait for process to terminate, but you can
// change this with WNOHANG in the options.

if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
   // exitted
} 

if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
    // process got a signal
    // WTERMSIG(status) will get you the signal that was sent.
}
```

**AIX:**

The solution will need some adaptation to work with AIX, have a look at the doc there:

- ptrace documentation: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/ptrace.htm
- waitpid documentation: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/ptrace.htm

**Solaris**

As mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708859/ptrace-in-solaris) ptrace may not be available on your version of Solaris, you may have to resort to procfs there.

Comment: OP also asked for AIX and Solaris. The code will not work for AIX and Solaris or OS X, for that matter.

Comment: Also see [ptrace in solaris](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6708859/608639). I believe Solaris removed the ptrace interfaces. What remains uses `/proc`.

Comment: On Solaris, use `poll` on the `/proc/###/psinfo` file. https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/ptools/pwait/pwait.c

Comment: OP also asked about unrelated process.